# How to prevent BIOS from corruption

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

I went to my computer this morning, and it appeared to be off (It's usually on). The power button wasn't doing anything, and there was still power going through the USB ports (Normally there isn't power going to it when the PC itself is off). I turned it on by unplugging it and plugging it back in, but when it turned on again, I got this message:

[image: BIOS error]

Everything seems to be working fine now, but I want to know what might have caused this in the first place, and how to prevent it from happening again. I know flashing the BIOS can cause problems like this, but I haven't done anything like that to this PC before, and haven't done anything out-of-the-ordinary. The computer is mostly just used for web browsing and some accounting/office stuff- Nothing that would be risky in any way. It hasn't been overclocked either.

I ran [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/), and everything looked fine there.

**Specs:**

- Motherboard // GIGABYTE 970A-D3P
- Ram // 16GB DDR4 (4x4gb)
- CPU // AMD FX-8350
- OS // Windows 10 home edition (Up to date)

Comment: My first thought, assuming it's a somewhat old machine, is the CMOS battery is out and needs replacing. Otherwise, if it's a one-off, blame it on cosmic rays. If it keeps happening, consider replacing the motherboard.

Comment: @Bob It's not even a year old, but maybe it'd be worth replacing anyways.

Comment: the BIOS is a program that exists on an EEPROM on your motherboard. it is loaded into RAM at power-on, and a set of settings for it are loaded from CMOS storage (another chip on the motherboard, that is writable by the BIOS setup program).  The message you are seeing indicates that either the EEPROM storage has become corrupted, or that the CMOS memory is corrupt. from the message I'd assume its the BIOS program itself. Causes might include significant power fluctuations, an ageing board, or even the release of an alpha-partical that impacted on a storage cell, flipping bits.